# How to to switch to a new git branch whilst preserving changes in "new" files

Tags: git

Suppose I have two git branches `A` and `B` and a file `b` that occurs in `B` but not `A`.  Sometimes I might make modifications to `b` whilst `A` is checked out (unintentionally, but it is still there in my editor).  If I try to `checkout` `B` then git will complain because `b` contains changes that would be overwritten.

How can I checkout `B` and keep all my changes to `b`?

(`git checkout --force` does not work, because `b` will be overwritten. `git stash` does not work because `b` does not exist in `A`.)

Comment: "Sometimes I might make modifications to b whilst A is checked out" How are you modifying a file that is not present on the branch? Switching to `A` definitely *should* delete `b`.

Comment: Most changes don't prevent you from switching branches. When it actually does (because part of the currently uncommited changes would be overridden), committing or stashing *are* effective ways to solve the problem.

Comment: [`git stash push --include-untracked`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-push-p--patch-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quiet-m--messageltmessagegt--ltpathspecgt82308203)

Comment: @RomainValeri: Yes, you're right.  I edited the comment.  The problem remains because the file is still there in my editor and I can easily make edits to it without realising it doesn't exist on the filesystem.

Comment: @phd You should write that up as an answer.

Comment: @RomainValeri: As I explained, `stash` doesn't work in this case because the file is not tracked.  Committing seems a bit heavyweight.

Comment: @phd: I don't want to stash *all* untracked files.  If I do `git stash push --include-untracked <filename>` then I get an error when I switch branches and try to pop ("already exists, no checkout Could not restore untracked files from stash entry")

Comment: @TomEllis You should [edit] your question to include these things you have tried along with the full error messages that each attempt gives.

Comment: There's an ugly method: `mv b b.out-of-the-way`, checkout, then `mv b b.from-other-branch; mv b.out-of-the-way b` for instance. Now reconcile the two versions of `b` manually. The thing is, you've stored one version *in* Git and Git will insist on getting it back out, and you've stored one version untracked in your work-tree and Git will insist on not clobbering it. So move the work-tree-only copy out of the way first.